# How to fix the width of a bulletproof button in Microsoft Surface?

Tags: html, email, button, outlook

I'm not a developer and this is my first question so please forgive my formatting, etc. I'd be grateful for any help.

I'm using a bulletproof button from here: https://gist.github.com/elidickinson/9424116 in a number of HTML emails.

It works really well in a large range of clients and devices with minimal issues, but when viewed in Outlook on a Surface, much of the text is cut off.

I have tried adjusting the widths without success. I know that the commented code is designed to work with Outlook (which it does), but apparently not on the Surface?

Initially I used:

```
<tr>
 <td valign="top" style="font-size:0px; padding-left:30px;">
   <div>
    <!--[if mso]>
      <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://www.example.com"  style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:150px;" arcsize="10%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#FFB549">
        <w:anchorlock/>
        <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;">
          Go to my home
        </center>
      </v:roundrect>
      <![endif]-->
      <![if !mso]>
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> <tr> 
      <td align="center" width="150" height="40" bgcolor="#FFB549" style="-webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; color: #ffffff; display: block;">
        <a href="http://www.example.com"  style="font-size:16px; font-weight: bold; font-family:sans-serif; text-decoration: none; line-height:40px; width:100%; display:inline-block">
        <span style="color: #ffffff;">
          Go to my home
        </span>
        </a>
      </td> 
      </tr> </table> 
      <![endif]>
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
```

And have also tried:

```
<tr>
 <td valign="top" style="font-size:0px; padding-left:30px;">
   <div>
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> <tr> 
      <td align="center" width="150" height="40" bgcolor="#FFB549" style="-webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; color: #ffffff; display: block;">
       <!--[if mso]>
      <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://www.example.com"  style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:150px;" arcsize="10%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#FFB549">
        <w:anchorlock/>
        <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;">
          Go to my home
        </center>
      </v:roundrect>
      <![endif]-->
      <![if !mso]>
           <a href="http://www.example.com"  style="font-size:16px; font-weight: bold; font-family:sans-serif; text-decoration: none; line-height:40px; width:100%; display:inline-block">
        <span style="color: #ffffff;">
          Go to my home
        </span>
        </a>
       <![endif]> 
      </td> 
      </tr> 
      </table> 
    </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
 </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using bulletproof buttons from the actual source?
http://buttons.cm/

Can't say if this will fix the Surface issue as I don't have a test device, but the github code and the buttons.cm code differ, such as another table inside the div which seems odd to me.

Comment: Yes I did use that code originally. But I couldn't get the button looking right in Outlook on the PC. The coloured background of the button only just surrounded the text.